# IDocumentFilter to hide/show unauthorised apis from swagger doc

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, swashbuckle

In swashbuckle 2.2.0(with swagger 2.0), after authorize the response is on a popup unlike 1.1.0 (which used to be a page load)

We have had something similar to hide/show unauthorized api's if the context user authentication is not authenticated hides/ vice versa.

[Github Swashbuckle issue](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/641)  hoping someone might have a solution or tried this already.

The authentication context is not being sent to reload the page which kicks the IdocumentFilter.

```
public class HideUnauthorizedOperations : IDocumentFilter
{
    private IHttpContextAccessor _httpContext;

    public HideUnauthorizedOperations(IHttpContextAccessor httpContext)
    {
        _httpContext = httpContext;
    }

    public void Apply(SwaggerDocument swaggerDoc, DocumentFilterContext context)
    {

        var authenticated = _httpContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
        //TODO context user is null, need to fix the authentication
        //if (!authenticated)
        //{
        //    foreach (var values in swaggerDoc.Paths.Values)
        //    {
        //        var nullifyThese = new List<Operation>();
        //        foreach (var operation in values.EnumerateOperations())
        //        {
        //            if (operation != null && operation.Security?.Count > 0)
        //                nullifyThese.Add(operation);
        //        }
        //        values.NullifyOperations(nullifyThese);
        //    }
        //}
    }

}
```